# Formatting pandas dataframe from list of nested dictionaries

Tags: python, pandas

I am new to Panda and struggle to get my head wrapped around this. I have not been able to find a good answer for my problem after looking for a while. I am trying to create a Pandas dataframe from a list of dictionaries.

My list of nested dictionaries is the following:

```
"iam": {
    "data": [
      {
        "Account": "123",
        "Alias": "aws-alias-123",
        "Roles": [
          {
            "Role": "ADFS-111"
          },
          {
            "Role": "ADFS-222"
          },
          {
            "Role": "ADFS-333"
          }
        ],
        "Users": []
      },
      {
        "Account": "456",
        "Alias": "aws-alias-456",
        "Roles": [
          {
            "Role": "ADFS-444"
          },
          {
            "Role": "ADFS-555"
          },
          {
            "Role": "ADFS-666"
          }
        ],
        "Users": []
      },
      {
        "Account": "789",
        "Alias": "aws-alias-789",
        "Roles": [
          {
            "Role": "ADFS-777"
          },
          {
            "Role": "ADFS-888"
          },
          {
            "Role": "ADFS-999"
          }
        ],
        "Users": []
      },
    ]
  }
```

My current code:

```
roles = pd.DataFrame(event['iam']['data']).explode('Roles', ignore_index=True).reindex(columns=['Account','Roles'])
```

Is producing

```
  Account       Roles
0   123   {'Role': 'ADFS-111'}
1   123   {'Role': 'ADFS-222'}
2   123   {'Role': 'ADFS-333'}
3   456   {'Role': 'ADFS-444'}
4   456   {'Role': 'ADFS-555'}
5   456   {'Role': 'ADFS-666'}
6   789   {'Role': 'ADFS-777'}
7   789   {'Role': 'ADFS-888'}
8   789   {'Role': 'ADFS-999'}
```

I'd like the output of

```
Account   Roles
123       ADFS-111
          ADFS-222
          ADFS-333
456       ADFS-444
          ADFS-555
          ADFS-666
789       ADFS-777
          ADFS-888
          ADFS-999
```

If possible.

Answer (score 0):

I hope this answer solves your problem

Setup:

```
data = {
    "iam": {
        "data": [
            {
                "Account": "123",
                "Alias": "aws-alias-123",
                "Roles": [
                    {"Role": "ADFS-111"},
                    {"Role": "ADFS-222"},
                    {"Role": "ADFS-333"}],
                "Users": []
            },
            {
                "Account": "456",
                "Alias": "aws-alias-456",
                "Roles": [
                    {"Role": "ADFS-444"},
                    {"Role": "ADFS-555"},
                    {"Role": "ADFS-666"}],
                "Users": []
            },
            {
                "Account": "789",
                "Alias": "aws-alias-789",
                "Roles": [
                    {"Role": "ADFS-777"},
                    {"Role": "ADFS-888"},
                    {"Role": "ADFS-999"}],
                "Users": []
            },
        ]
    }
}
```

Code:

```py
import pandas as pd

df = pd.json_normalize(data['iam']['data'], 'Roles', ['Account'], record_prefix='Roles.')
df = df.explode('Roles.Role')
df = df.rename(columns={'Roles.Role': 'Roles'})
df = df.loc[:, ['Account', 'Roles']]
print(df)
```

The result

```
  Account     Roles
0     123  ADFS-111
1     123  ADFS-222
2     123  ADFS-333
3     456  ADFS-444
4     456  ADFS-555
5     456  ADFS-666
6     789  ADFS-777
7     789  ADFS-888
8     789  ADFS-999
```

Comment: I don't think you actually need the `.explode()`. I got the right result with just `json_normalize(event['iam']['data'], 'Roles', ['Account'])` (but with `Role` instead of `Roles` (which IMO is better) and the columns backwards). But I haven't used `json_normalize` very much, myself.

Comment: Yeahh thanks for telling me about that. there no need the .explode(), the result will same. Once again thanks.

Comment: Is there a way to format the last part of the question? Not showing the duplicate account numbers?